# Where can I find third-party components?

Tags: android

Where can I find third-party components for the Android?  Components such as dials, meters, graphics of volume controls LED's, etc?

Answer (score 2):

What Macarse said: There's no one-stop shop for that. However, code.google.com has a bunch of good projects (http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Android), and then of course you can just Google for stuff.

What you should do is figure out what you actually need, and google for those things specifically. So if you need a dial component, just google for "android dial component" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such place.
You should use Google to get some of those.

Answer (score 0):

See [The Android Arsenal- A categorized directory of free libraries and tools for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/)
Contains ~1000 libraries and ~90 sample projects.